# How to get the date of the last business day of the week in R?

Tags: r, bizdays

I want to know if today is the last business day of this week in R.
I was thinking of using `getdate()` from `Bizdays` library, so I created the calendar inputting the holidays in my country.
however, in the next step of actually using `getdate()` function, it only accepts "year" and "month" as reference, not "week".

```r
library(bizdays)
create.calendar(name='Indonesia', holidays = tbl_Libur$Tanggal,
       weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'), financial = FALSE)
date.now <- Sys.Date()
    
getdate("last bizday", ref(date.now, "week"), "Indonesia")
```

the result of the code above is

```
Error in match.arg(ym) : 'arg' should be one of “month”, “year”
```

Is there a better/simpler way of doing it, or I will have to brute force evaluating each day of the week using `is.bizday()` and get the last true value like this?

```
weekStart <- date.now - wday(date.now) + 1

for(i in 0:6){
  tgl <- weekStart + i
  if(is.bizday(tgl, "Indonesia")){
    result <- tgl  
  }
}
result
```

Thanks